How to plot boxes that correlate with technical indicator
I am trying to plot boxes on my chart that correlate with the technical indicator I am using. The indicator is the MACD. Basically, what I want it to do is create a green box when there is a long crossover, then end that box when the crossover is over. And vice versa with a red box for a short crossunder.
I want it too look something like this image below...
enter image description here
I tried the following code...
// Detecting crossovers
longCondition = ta.crossover(MACD, Signal)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(MACD, Signal)

// Plotting boxes
boxLength = 10 // Length of the box in bars
if (longCondition)
    for i = 0 to boxLength + 1
        box.new(bar_index[i], close[i], bar_index, open, bgcolor=color.green, border_color=color.green)

if (shortCondition)
    for i = 0 to boxLength - 1
        box.new(bar_index[i], low[i], bar_index, high, bgcolor=color.red, border_color=color.red)

Which resulted in this image below
enter image description here
I am not worried about the color. I didn't code in any transperancy. However, has you can see the placement of the boxes is very off.
I have not tried any code as I cannot really think of any other solution. It has me quite stumped.
